# SQLCommand.Parameters.Add - How to give decimal value size?

Tags: c#, sqlparameter

How would you specify this:

```
Decimal(18,2)
```

In this:

```
SqlComm.Parameters.Add("@myValue", SqlDbType.Decimal, 0, "myValue");
```

Currently I have defined `precision = 2` from the design side properties. I'm just curious as to how to accomplish this from the code. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need extra precision if the parameter value is 0?

Comment: Precision value dictates how many digits after the decimal you have, correct? Currently it's 0 just as a placeholder for this question. I"m just curious how to set (18,2) for the decimal size from the code.

Comment: You can either round it in C# using `Math.Round` or take the value as is and round in your SQL statement.

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.precision(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In respect to @NoChance comment above, the relevant part is: _**You do not need to specify values for the Precision and Scale properties for input parameters, as they can be inferred from the parameter value.**_

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's not an overload of `Add` that lets you set the decimal precision inline, so you either need to create a SQlParameter object and add it to the collection:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@myValue", SqlDbType.Decimal);
param.SourceColumn = "myValue";
param.Precision = 18;
param.Scale = 2;
SqlComm.Parameters.Add(param);
```

or keep a reference to the parameter after adding it:

```
SqlParameter param = SqlComm.Parameters.Add("@myValue", SqlDbType.Decimal, 0, "myValue");
param.Precision = 18;
param.Scale = 2;
```

or using the parameter constructor:

```
SqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(
    parameterName = "@myValue", 
    dbType = SqlDbType.Decimal,
    precision = 18,
    scale = 2,
    sourceColumn = "myValue"));
```

Comment: No need to find the parameter after adding it, `SqlParameterCollection.Add` returns the newly created parameter. `SqlParameter param = SqlComm.Parameters.Add("@myValue", SqlDbType.Decimal, 0, "myValue");`

Comment: Do I need to set `Precision` and `Scale` property prior to assign the value to the `SqlParameter` ?

Comment: @hiFI No - just before executing the query.

Comment: Per Microsoft Documentation (See comments in original post) - you do not need to set the scale and precision on input parameters.

Comment: is there any way to do a one liner for this solution?

Comment: @Hacki Added an example.

Comment: ohh, we can't do it something like this: SqlComm.Parameters.Add("@myValue", SqlDbType.Decimal, precision, scale, "myValue"); right?

Comment: @Hacki Yes, you can because the parameters to the constructor line up that way - I was just being explicit for all parameters and not relying on parameter order.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand()
SetDecimalParameter(cmd.Parameters.Add("@paramName", SqlDbType.Decimal), 18, 2).Value = 12.34;

SqlParameter SetDecimalParameter(SqlParameter parameter, byte precision, byte scale) {
            parameter.Precision = precision;
            parameter.Scale = scale;
            return parameter;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not directly connected with the OP's question, but I've seen a lot of people asking "why set the precision since it is taken from the value".

It has to do with the way SQL Server works when comparing the decimal parameter with the text column. Imagine you have column named `strNumberColumn` witch is of *nvarchar* type. If you define a `@var Decimal(1,0) = '1'`, comparison on the condition `where strNumberColumn >= @var` will work only as long, as the longest entry in that column is between "0" and "9". If any of the entries go beyond, for example "10" or "123" you will get an *OverflowException* while converting string to decimal. What is important, that conversion is made "behind the scenes".

Please, do not bring arguments like "if that column should contain numbers it should not be made nvarchar" - I totally agree, but that is beyond the scope of the problem (sometimes you work with a legacy system and you have no influence over the column datatype). The above example shows a real life scenario when defining precision is required in order for the query to run successfully despite having a smaller precision amount assigned to the variable (like `@var Decimal(12,2) = '1.0'`).