# Why is a string expected at this point?

Tags: sql-server, int32, commandparameter

From an answer or comment to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64212096/why-am-i-getting-an-exception-telling-me-that-i-need-to-declare-a-scalar-variabl), I was directed [here](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

So I changed my code from this:

```
double _imdbThreshold = 0.0;
(IMDBRating is a Decimal(2,1) data type in the SQL Server (Express) Database.)
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMDBMinRating", _imdbThreshold);
```

...to this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMDBMinRating", SqlDbType.Decimal, 2, 1).Value = _imdbThreshold;
```

...based on this example in the article linked above:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter", SqlDbType.Decimal, 11, 4).Value = MyDecimalVariable;
```

But I get, "Cannot convert from int to string":

[image]

?!?

Why is it finding fault with my "1" int arg there?

Comment: There is no overload `(String, SqlDbType, Int32, Int32)`, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1). You need to set the precision and scale [separately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31391922/2029983).

Comment: Yes, so the article referenced was wrong. I wonder if it worked at the time it was written, or nobody has tested it.

Comment: ^^ Dirks comment mentions exactly that i.e. that that method is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a reference any more, but years ago when using SqlHelper, the guidance came with a number of [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) that simplify working with `SqlCommand` and `SqlParameter`.

The following extension method will allow your code to work, I can only speculate but I suspect the code you referenced used a similar extension method and they were not aware it was not part of the standard runtime.
*a very easy mistake to make!*

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Adds a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter given the specified parameter name,
/// System.Data.SqlDbType, size <i>AND</i> precision.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="self">The SqlParameterCollection to add the parameter to.</param>
/// <param name="parameterName">The name of the parameter to map.</param>
/// <param name="dbType">One of the System.Data.SqlDbType values.</param>
/// <param name="size">The length of the parameter.</param>
/// <param name="precision">The precision of the parameter.</param>
/// <returns>The System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter object that was initialized and added to the collection.</returns>
public static SqlParameter Add(this SqlParameterCollection self, string parameterName, SqlDbType dbType, int size, byte precision)
{
    return self.Add(new SqlParameter(parameterName, dbType, size) { Precision = precision });
}
```

I find this syntax simpler to read when you stare at a lot of these all day, but it is also consistent with the standard `Add` methods for types that do not support precision:

```cs
decimal myDecimalVariable = 19.8M;
int myIntVariable = 2;
string myStringVariable = "Test";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter1", SqlDbType.Decimal, 11, 4).Value = myDecimalVariable;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = myIntVariable;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter3", SqlDbType.Char, 4).Value = myStringVariable;
```

---

Given the number of other existing methods, I can only imagine that the original developers simply *forgot* to include this simple method in the `SqlParameterCollection` definition.

Answer (score 0):

A [different article](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) on the "evils" of AddWithValue() uses this example for a Decimal type parameter:

```
command.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter("@InvoiceTotal", SqlDbType.Decimal) { Precision = 18, Scale = 4, Value = 1234.56m });
```

So I changed my code to this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IMDBMinRating", SqlDbType.Decimal) { Precision = 2, Scale = 1, Value = _imdbThreshold });
```

...and it compiles now.

It's all good now, this way:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IMDBMinRating", SqlDbType.Decimal) { 
                       Precision = 2, Scale = 1, Value = _imdbThreshold });
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EarliestYear", SqlDbType.Char, 4).Value = _yearBegin;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LatestYear", SqlDbType.Char, 4).Value = _yearEnd;
```